# how to add a primefaces contextmenu to datatable header?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, contextmenu

i'm using `primefaces` and i want to add a `ContextMenu` only for `datatable` header, but i'm using the `columns` component to handle the `dynamic` columns generation, i know how to add a Contextmenu for every column but i want to generate one context menu for them all.

```
<p:column id="col1">
 <p:contextMenu  style="
            font-size:11px!important;
            text-align:left!important;
           margin-left: 0px!important;" >
 <c:forEach items="#{dyna.columnnameslist}" var="ccm">
   <p:menuitem  value="#{ccm}"/>
 </c:forEach>
 </p:contextMenu>
<p:column>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
<p:column id="col1">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Your Label" id="hLabel" />
        <p:contextMenu for="hLabel"  style="font-size:11px!important; text-align:left!important; margin-left: 0px!important;">
            <c:forEach items="#{dyna.columnnameslist}" var="ccm">
                <p:menuitem  value="#{ccm}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </p:contextMenu>
    </f:facet>
<p:column>
```

Comment: Don't forget to do some "cssing" to make your label text fill the entire header column.

Comment: i think this works for one column, i have this working, what i need is to show the same context menu for the whole table header, ( context menu with checkboxes and column names to specify which columns to show)

Comment: i ve used teh facet and now it's working like a charm.

Comment: but i wonder about two things : 1-make the whole label not only the text as an invoke for the context menu,2-make the context menu show in the south not north.